# How to sign transaction using Oracle Service in Corda?

Tags: corda

I'm trying to sign a transaction using Oracle service in Corda.For this, I'm using a function specified in Corda docs.

```
fun commandValidator(elem: Command<*>): Boolean {
    require(services.myInfo.legalIdentities.first().owningKey in elem.signers && elem.value is Fix) {
        "Oracle received unknown command (not in signers or not Fix)."
    }
    val fix = elem.value as Fix
    val known = knownFixes[fix.of]
    if (known == null || known != fix)
        throw UnknownFix(fix.of)
    return true
}
```

But when I try using the above function , I'm getting error for "knownFixes" and "UnknownFix()" as unresolved reference .

a) How to solve this issue (how do I declare or import these)?

b) Is this approach the right way to do signing transaction from Oracle Service?

Comment: Do you have a link to the docs you're referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`knownFixes` and `UnknownFix` are CorDapp-specific code defined as part of the [IRS sample](https://github.com/corda/corda/tree/master/samples/irs-demo).

Signing as the oracle is as simple as:

```
@CordaService
class Oracle(val services: ServiceHub) : SingletonSerializeAsToken() {
    fun sign(ftx: FilteredTransaction): TransactionSignature {
        val myKey = services.myInfo.legalIdentities.first().owningKey
        return services.createSignature(ftx, myKey)
    }
}
```

But you would normally want to do additional checking, to ensure you're happy with what you're signing. The checks are up to you. Here's an example of an oracle that checks whether a number embedded in a command is a prime number:

```
@CordaService
class Oracle(val services: ServiceHub) : SingletonSerializeAsToken() {
    private val myKey = services.myInfo.legalIdentities.first().owningKey

    // Generates a list of natural numbers and filters out the non-primes.
    // The reason why prime numbers were chosen is because they are easy to reason about and reduce the mental load
    // for this tutorial application.
    // Clearly, most developers can generate a list of primes and all but the largest prime numbers can be verified
    // deterministically in reasonable time. As such, it would be possible to add a constraint in the
    // [PrimeContract.verify] function that checks the nth prime is indeed the specified number.
    private val primes = generateSequence(1) { it + 1 }.filter { BigInteger.valueOf(it.toLong()).isProbablePrime(16) }

    // Returns the Nth prime for N > 0.
    fun query(n: Int): Int {
        require(n > 0) { "n must be at least one." } // URL param is n not N.
        return primes.take(n).last()
    }

    // Signs over a transaction if the specified Nth prime for a particular N is correct.
    // This function takes a filtered transaction which is a partial Merkle tree. Any parts of the transaction which
    // the oracle doesn't need to see in order to verify the correctness of the nth prime have been removed. In this
    // case, all but the [PrimeContract.Create] commands have been removed. If the Nth prime is correct then the oracle
    // signs over the Merkle root (the hash) of the transaction.
    fun sign(ftx: FilteredTransaction): TransactionSignature {
        // Check the partial Merkle tree is valid.
        ftx.verify()

        /** Returns true if the component is an Create command that:
         *  - States the correct prime
         *  - Has the oracle listed as a signer
         */
        fun isCommandWithCorrectPrimeAndIAmSigner(elem: Any) = when {
            elem is Command<*> && elem.value is PrimeContract.Create -> {
                val cmdData = elem.value as PrimeContract.Create
                myKey in elem.signers && query(cmdData.n) == cmdData.nthPrime
            }
            else -> false
        }

        // Is it a Merkle tree we are willing to sign over?
        val isValidMerkleTree = ftx.checkWithFun(::isCommandWithCorrectPrimeAndIAmSigner)

        if (isValidMerkleTree) {
            return services.createSignature(ftx, myKey)
        } else {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Oracle signature requested over invalid transaction.")
        }
    }
}
```